# On the properties of a projection map from points in the bulk to qubits on the boundary

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, mathematical-physics, holographic-principle, geometry

Note: I have completely re-edited my post, so as to make it much clearer. I apologize for the previous version of this post, which I had written rather fast.

Let $H^3$ denote hyperbolic $3$-space and let $C_n$ denote the configuration space of $n$ distinct points in $H^3$. We think of $H^3$ as an open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and use the Poincare model of $H^3$. By the sphere at infinity, we mean the unit sphere in this model, i.e. the boundary of the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It makes sense to give this $2$-sphere a complex structure using stereographic projection, and thus think of this $2$-sphere as $\mathbb{C}P^1$, the complex projective line (aka the Riemann sphere). Note that $\mathbb{C}P^1$ can be thought of as the space of quantum states of a single qubit.

Let us for the time being fix a configuration $\mathbf{x} = (\mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n) \in C_n$.

Denote by $P$ the set of all pairs of indices $(i, j)$, with $1 \leq i, j \leq n$ and $i \neq j$. For each $(i, j) \in P$, we denote by $\psi_{ij}$ the point on the sphere at infinity (i.e. $\mathbb{C}P^1$, using our remarks above) obtained as the limiting point of a hyperbolic geodesic ray starting from $\mathbf{x}_i$ and passing through $\mathbf{x}_j$.

We define $Q_n = \prod_{(i,j) \in P} \mathbb{C}P^1$ and define the smooth map $\pi: C_n \to Q_n$ which maps a configuration $\mathbf{x} \in C_n$ to the corresponding tuple of $n(n-1)$ points on $\mathbb{C}P^1$, i.e. to the corresponding $(\psi_{ij})$.

Note that $H^3$ and $C_n$ are geometric. One can induce a Riemannian metric on $C_n$ from $H^3$. On the other hand, $\mathbb{C}P^1$ and $Q_n$ may perhaps be thought of as quantum information theoretic. Note that $\mathbb{C}^2$ can be endowed with a complex symplectic form $\omega \in \Lambda^2(\mathbb{C}^2)^*$, defined as
$$ \omega((u_1, v_1), (u_2, v_2)) = u_1 v_2 - u_2 v_1. $$
In turn, $\omega$ induces a holomorphic section of $\mathcal{O}(1,1)$ on $\mathbb{C}P^1 \times \mathbb{C}P^1$. This is the kind of structure one has on $\mathbb{C}P^1$, and this induces a similar structure on $Q_n$. More precisely, for each $I_1 = (i_1, j_1)$, $I_2 = (i_2, j_2) \in P$, with $I_1 \neq I_2$, one has an $\omega_{I_1\,I_2}$, which is a holomorphic section of $\mathcal{O}(1,1)$ on $(\mathbb{C}P^1)_{I_1} \times (\mathbb{C}P^1)_{I_2}$ (where $(\mathbb{C}P^1)_{(i,j)}$ is the copy of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ corresponding to the direction from point $\mathbf{x}_i$ to point $\mathbf{x}_j$).

Question 1: is it possible to recover the smooth Riemannian metric on $C_n$ using the map $\pi$ and the structure $(\omega_{I_1 \, I_2})$ on $Q_n$?

Question 2: does this have possibly anything to do with the so-called holographic principle in physics (perhaps after a Wick rotation), which is why I am asking this question here?

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this question please? Please explain to me. I am looking for a physical interpretation of the Atiyah-Sutcliffe determinant using qubits. This may or may not exist, but I don't understand why someone voted to close my post...

Comment: I don't understand much of your question, tbh, but since you mentioned 'geometry' and 'qubits', it might be worth to take a look into *Geometry of Quantum States.
An Introduction to Quantum Entanglement. Ingemar Bengtsson and Karol Życzkowski. Cambridge University Press*. But again, since I don't understand much, that is just a guess.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker, I completely rewrote my post. Please let me know if it is clear now. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Oh, I am very sorry: I do not understand much due to my lack of knowledge, not due to the structure of the post. That being said, making the question clearer of course improves the chances of getting high quality answers. I've edited the tags; feel free to undo if needed.